# Criterion for the Existence of a Bounded Left Approximate Identity

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading through the text "Complete Normed Algebras" by F.F. Bonsall and John Duncan and I'm having some troubles understanding proposition 2 in chapter 1, section 11 (page 58) regarding the existence of a bounded left approximate identity for a normed algebra.

The definition I am using for bounded left approximate identity is:

**Definition:** Let $ A $ be a normed algebra.  A **bounded left approximate identity** is a net $ \{ e(\lambda) \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda} $ such that $ e(\lambda)x \to x $ for every $ x \in A $ and there exists a $ K > 0 $ such that $ \| e(\lambda) \| \leq K $ for all $ \lambda \in \Lambda $.**

Proposition 2 on page 58 states:

**Proposition 2:** Let $ A $ contain a bounded set $ U $ such that, given $ x \in A $, $ \epsilon > 0 $ there exists $ u \in U $ with $ \| x - ux \| < \epsilon $.  Then $ A $ has a bounded left approximate identity.

For $ \epsilon > 0 $, it is shown in the proof that for any finite subset $ F $ of $ A $ there exists a $ w \in W = \{ v \circ u : v, u \in U \} $ such that:

$$ \| x - wx \| < \epsilon $$

Where $ v \circ u := v + u - vu $ is the quasi-product of $ v $ and $ u $.  The authors prove this by induction (which is fairly straightforward to follow).

The authors then state that "the result is then clear by consideration of the product directed set $ \mathbb{N} \times F(A) $ where $ F(A) $ denotes the directed set of all finite subsets of $ A $."

I am not sure what this means, perhaps because I am not that familiar with nets.  Explicitly, what net becomes the bounded left approximate identity for $ X $?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!